Was the half tribe of Manasseh given land twice in the book of Numbers?
I'm going thru Numbers and maybe I missed something.  Numbers 32:33-39 mentions Moses giving land to the Gadites, Reubenites and the half-tribe of Manasseh.  Later in Numbers 34:17-29, it names one leader from each tribe to help assign land to the "remaining" tribes.  The tribes of Reuben and Gad aren't in the list understandably because they got their share in Numbers 32 but Manasseh is in the list. (v 23).
Why is Manasseh listed twice to receive land?  Did I miss something important in an earlier passage or did I misunderstand something that happened in the history of the Israelites exodus?  Am I misunderstanding what "half-tribe" means?

This is where a map helps.
The answer is that Manasseh was divided in two, making two half-tribes.
One half-tribe received land on the eastern side of Jordan (Numbers ch32), alongside Reuben and Gad.
The other half-tribe received land on the western side of the Jordan, just north of Ephraim territory. Numbers ch34 vv17-29 is one of the passages relating to the division of land on the west (Reuben and Gad are missing).
This division is spelled out again in Joshua, where ch13 describes the transjordan inheritances, and the boundaries of the western half-tribe are detailed in ch17.
Thus Manasseh as a whole straddled the river, as is usually shown in the maps at the end of Bibles.
